# componentDidMount is being fired multiple times in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I am calling an api using axios inside `componentDidMount` and the api is being called multiple times.

Here is my code

```
export default class Listings extends Component{

state = {
    listings: null
}

//when the component is mounted to dom first
componentDidMount() {
    this.getAllCryptoListings();
}

getAllCryptoListings() {
    let response = null;

    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/')
        .then( (res) => {
                response = res;
                console.log(response.data.data);
            })
        .catch( (error) => console.log(error) )
        .finally( () => { this.setState({listings: response.data.data}) } )
}

}
```

Normally I expected the code to run one time only as per the description of the function here [componentDidMount.](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) 
The documentation says

**You may call setState() immediately in componentDidUpdate() but note that it must be wrapped in a condition like in the example above, or you’ll cause an infinite loop. It would also cause an extra re-rendering which, while not visible to the user, can affect the component performance.**

How to make the code inside `componentDidMount` run only once?

Comment: Do you use react 18?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski yes react 18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`componentDidMount()` is called twice if you `setState` in it, you won't be able to disable this.

You can make your call in `componentWillMount`, but this is *UNSAFE* so be careful using it! (not recommended)

If this does not work you should check where your component is called. Maybe his parents are re-rendering and so calling the render to verify twice with the initial state.

You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59990063/component-did-mount-gets-called-twice-if-i-set-state-within-after-fetching-data)

In React version 18, a change was made to `strict mode` so that components will mount, then unmount, then mount again. This was added to help us all start catching issues that will affect an upcoming feature. In a future version of react, the state will be able to be preserved between unmounts, and as a result, components may mount multiple times.

Comment: This is just not true https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-kirch-vwpykq?file=/src/App.js